# how to pass host user to Dockerfile when using docker-compose

Tags: command-line, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to pass a host variable to a `Dockerfile` when running `docker-compose build`

I would like to run

```
RUN usermod -u $USERID www-data
```

in an `apache-php7` `Dockerfile`. `$USERID` being the ID of the current host user.

I would have thought that the following might work:

**commandline**

```
EXPORT USERID=$(id -u); docker-compose build
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
environment:
    - USERID=$USERID
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ENV USERID 
RUN usermod -u $USERID www-data
```

But no luck yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Docker in general it is generally not possible to use host environment variables during the *build* phase; this is because it is desirable that if you run `docker build` and I run `docker build` using the same Dockerfile (or Docker Hub runs `docker build with the same Dockerfile), we end up with the same image, regardless of our local environment.

While passing in variables at *runtime* is easy with the `docker` command line (using `-e <var>=<value>`), it's a little trickier with `docker-compose`, because that tool is designed to create self-contained environments.

A simple solution would be to drop the host uid into an environment file before starting the container.  That is, assuming you have:

```
version: "2"

services:
  shell:
    image: alpine
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    command: >
      env
```

You can then:

```
echo HOST_UID=$UID > docker-compose.env; docker-compose up
```

And the `HOST_UID` environment variable will be available to your
container:

```
Recreating vartest_shell_1
Attaching to vartest_shell_1
shell_1  | HOSTNAME=17423d169a25
shell_1  | HOST_UID=1000
shell_1  | HOME=/root
vartest_shell_1 exited with code 0
```

You would then to have something like an `ENTRYPOINT` script that
would set up the container environment (creating users, modifying file
ownership) to operate correctly with the given UID.